# Audi A3 Brake warning after MOT

Tags: brakes, audi, sensor, warning-light

just dropping in to show my support for this forum and to ask a quick question!

Had my '06 Audi A3 2.0 TDI Quattro Sport serviced and MOT'd yesterday. Knew my front pads were **very** worn (tried to change them myself but was sent the wrong parts) so asked the guy to change them aswell.

Previously I hadn't had any warning lights regarding the pads being worn... Nor the rears (which were replaced a month or 2 ago). Now after the change and MOT my car's warning me that the brake pads are worn! I can clearly see the new pads are fitted correctly and have plenty of wear on them... So my question is:

Can the signal cable/sensor wire be incorrectly plugged in/setup?

Comment: Yes, basically a road worthy test of a vehicle for insurance and licencing reasons.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that they either fitted brake pads that don't have wear sensors or didn't connect the wear sensors correctly.

Comment: Can the wear sensor be connect in reverse? I was not previously getting a warning of my pads being worn. I now am with new pads?

Comment: I doubt that - normally it's a single wire, some have two but even then it doesn't really matter much which way around they have been connected. Basically they rely on an electrode in the pad making contact with the disk and completing a circuit that way.

Comment: As far as I know the sensor in an A3 is on the left (driver) side. Guess only more expensive Audis like the A8 do have sensors on both sides.

Comment: It's also possible that the warning indicator "latches on" after it has been triggered once, for safety reasons, and the mechanic inadvertently activated it while replacing the pads but didn't bother to reset it. The car handbook may tell you how to reset all the warnings - it's often a procedure like turning the ignition on while holding some combination of other buttons pressed down.